# Why is the condition "order of K divides order of G" mentioned?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In the definition here :

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order-dominating_subgroup

> Is it necessary to mention the condition "The order of K divides the order 
>     of G" ?

If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, the order of $K$ should, by Lagrange's theorem, always divide the order of $G$, unless the order of $G$ is infinite, in which case the order of $K$ divides the order of $G$ by default.

I guess that it should be "...such the order of of $K$ divides the order of $H$" because the symbol-free definition sounds like it is meant this way, but I am not sure, whether this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a typographical error and $|K|$ dividing $|H|$ is the true condition.

The idea is that any subgroup $K$ that, based on order considerations alone, could potentially have a conjugate copy inside $H$, does.

Comment: This makes much more sense :)